# Converting spreadsheet into microsoft excel using Google Apps, but not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Used below code to convert spreadsheet into xlsx. 
Though looks to be working fine, But doesn't works same as Microsoft Excel. Looking help on alternative to convert spreadsheet into microsoft xlsx file or Blob.

Objective:
I have an API that accepts only Microsoft .xlsx with data available in Google Spreadsheet; and hence trying to convert spreadsheet into Microsoft xlsx.

My Code:

```
function exportToXlsx(){
  var fileId = "{{fileID_of_spreadsheet}}";
  var targetFolderID = "{{target_folderID}}";

  Logger.log("Input File ID: " + fileId);  
  try {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + fileId + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

    var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

    var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

    //set name to blob
    blob.setName(DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getName() + ".xlsx");

    //create the xlsx file
    var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(blob);

  } catch (f) {
    Logger.log(f.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't works same as Microsoft Excel" ?